# Angular 2 Is rendering page twice on child route

Tags: angular

I have the follow route in app.module.ts

```
{
    path: 'settings',
    component: SettingsPage,
    children: [
    {
      path: 'account',
      component: AccountSettings
    }, {
      path: 'profile',
      component: ProfileSettings
    }]
  }
```

My settingsPage component has:

```
<div>
  <div class="xui-heading-panel secondary">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Settings</h1>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li 
          *ngFor="let link of links"
          role="presentation">
          <a [routerLink]="[link.route]" routerLinkActive="active">{{link.title}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

When visiting /settings/profile the router outlet inside settings component re-displays the entire page again (e.g not just child page). How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it do it for the account route as well?  Try moving the Settings component to something like this: `{path: 'settings', children: [{path: "",     component: SettingsPage}, {path: 'account', component: AccountSettings}, {path: 'profile', component: ProfileSettings}]}`

Comment: What is wrong in this example? https://plnkr.co/edit/hUaaWX5FsjzC7FH1nEwC?p=preview

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in it.  You have it setup with a second `<router-outlet>` the child route is going to that one, so it looks like it's behaving correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys. So the issue was that I didn't have

`moduleId: __moduleName` (inside my @Component annotation), this meant the templateUrl wasn't requested relative to the component directory. So an HTTP request was sent to /page_settings.html, which caused my server to return the /index.html and the entire app was rendered inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps to anyone
I also faced this issue while lazily loading a module in children
example
`const routes: Routes = [ { path: "", component: SiteLayout, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [ { path: "search", loadChildren: () => import('./Search/search.module').then(m => m.SearchModule) } ] } ]`

here I was facing this re-rendering of page while routing to /search
after spending a significant amount of time I got to knows that the in search module the RouteeModule was not imported which was causing application to behave like thi.

Hope it will help anyone stucked.